# How can I prevent Google Colab from disconnecting?

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Is there a way to programmatically prevent [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) from disconnecting on a timeout?

[image]

The following describes the conditions causing a notebook to automatically disconnect:

> *Google Colab notebooks have an idle timeout of 90 minutes and absolute timeout of 12 hours. This means, if user does not interact with his Google Colab notebook for more than 90 minutes, its instance is automatically terminated. Also, maximum lifetime of a Colab instance is 12 hours.*

Naturally, we want to automatically squeeze the maximum out of the instance, [without having to manually interact with it constantly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkvoo.jpg). Here I will assume commonly seen system requirements:

- [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTS (Bionic Beaver), Windows 10, or Mac operating systems
- In case of Linux-based systems, using popular [desktop environments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) like [GNOME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME) 3 or [Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(user_interface))
- Firefox or Chromium browsers

I should point out here that such behavior **does not violate** [Google Colab's Terms of Use](https://colab.one/terms-of-use), although it is not encouraged according to their [FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html) (in short: morally it is not okay to use up all of the GPUs if you don't really need it).

---

My current solution is very dumb:

- First, I turn the screensaver off, so my screen is always on.
- I have an [Arduino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino) board, so I just turned it into a [rubber ducky USB](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-USB-Rubber-Ducky) device and make it emulate primitive user interaction while I sleep (just because I have it at hand for other use cases).

Are there better ways?

Comment: "Idle timeout of 90 minutes... if a user does not interact with his google Colab notebook for more than 90 minutes, its instance is automatically terminated."   That's bad because kerastuner is impossible to use then.  Google staff need to think harder, if they really want the public to use kerastuner.

Comment: How do I stop this script from executing?

Comment: Not a code but a small weight and backspace key on your system can do the trick for you. Hope you understood!

Comment: unfortunately, by march 2021 none of this methods works anymore, in fact after about 2-3 hours of session opened a window will pop up with a "not a robot" button, this window opens regardless of what you are doing (it can even pop up while you are writing), if you fail to click the button the session ends within minutes

Comment: My training lasts 40 minutes but there is anyway no way to carry it out. I wish the idle timeout was 90 minutes as you said

Answer (score 208):

As of March 2021, none of these methods will work as Google added a [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) button that randomly pops up after some time.

Prior to that, the solution was very easy, and didn't need any JavaScript. Just create a new cell at the bottom having the following line:

```py
while True:pass
```

Now keep the cell in the run sequence so that the infinite loop won't stop and thus keep your session alive.

*Old method:*

Set a JavaScript interval to click on the connect button every 60 seconds.

Open developer-settings (in your web-browser) with Ctrl+Shift+I then click on console tab and type this on the console prompt. (for mac press Option+Command+I)

```js
function ConnectButton(){
  console.log("Connect pushed");
  document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connectbutton").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click()
}
setInterval(ConnectButton,60000);
```

Comment: It says **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at ConnectButton**

Comment: It seems that you answer is outdated

Comment: Fixed it by updating JS selector

Comment: In Chrome, you can create a bookmark to activate this snippet on one click. Just create a bookmark with the following URL: `javascript:void(setInterval(function(){ console.log("Connect pushed"); document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click(); },60000))` (one-liner version of the same command). I'm not sure if this works in other browsers

Comment: Does the screensaver need to be turned off for this?

Comment: @qAp I found that it will still work even if you are on a different tab, or your screen is off due to screensaver (I've been training models for more than 10 hours)

Comment: The problem with this answer is that the notebook can disconnects and then the script only make it reconnect. If you are using Drive then you should need auth the drive account and then the train stops. Maybe a little scroll of the output tab should do the trick

Comment: @TanayKarve I added this comment to your answer as it was the top answer at the point of my writing this. Your solution and many others to this answer lack one important detail. If you do not assign the function used in `setInterval` (in your case `ConnectButton`) to a variable so there is no way to reference it if you need to stop it for any reason (using `clearInterval`. Could you update your answer to assign `ConnectButton` to a variable and send this variable to `setInterval`? i.e. `var connectButton = function ConnectButton {...}; setInterval(connectButton, 60000)`

Comment: @KolaB or you could just refresh the page. As per my understanding colab doesn't disconnect the session if the page is refreshed.

Comment: Can you explain how and why `while True:pass` works? Will this still work if I have a cell that takes, say 5 hours to finish running?

Comment: @helperFunction actually, he means that `while True:pass` will keep the notebook session when you aren't running any cell. If your cell takes lots of time to run, just keep the tab open and it won't be disconnected.

Comment: @MinhDao There is a 90 min timeout on Colab, even with the tab open

Comment: @helperFunction it's `idle` timeout. Running any cell will prevent colab from idling.

Comment: @MinhDao I just had faced this problem yesterday. It times out even when a cell is being run

Comment: @MinhDao Quoting from this question itself, "This means, if user does not interact with his Google Colab notebook for more than 90 minutes, its instance is automatically terminated"

Comment: Everyone says use this function, but where to use it? Inside the jupyter notebook file?

Comment: @mah65 open the console by pressing ctrl+shift+i on chrome. and type the function there and press enter.

Comment: I tried old method but google captcha appear, so it isn't worked. Which method is working on current google colab?

Comment: Anyone knows what's the latest method to prevent disconnection?

Comment: @TanayKarve Any way to prevent the execution from failing when the internet connection drops for a few seconds or minutes?

Comment: tested  2022/2/12, not working anymore.

Answer (score 68):

Since the id of the connect button is now changed to "colab-connect-button", the following code can be used to keep clicking on the button.

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

If still, this doesn't work, then follow the steps below:

1. Right-click on the connect button (on the top-right side of the colab)
2. Click on inspect
3. Get the HTML id of the button and substitute in the following code

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("Put ID here").click() // Change id here
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Comment: This is the current solution as per the new button ID (Feb-2020)

Comment: If google is ever going to try to make this not work (example: make it a class and have multiple fake invisible buttons with that same class) you can always instead of step 3: right click --> Copy --> Copy JS Path

Comment: Still getting same issue Runtime disconnected, The runtime disconnected due to inactivity

Comment: How do I stop this script from executing?

Comment: @MurtazaKamal Crtl + Shift + I , Go to Sources and click on pause button.

Comment: its creating new cell each minute

Comment: "[...by March 2021 none of these methods work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-can-i-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting?page=2&tab=createdasc#comment118402191_57113226)"

Answer (score 39):

For me the following examples:

- `document.querySelector("#connect").click()` or
- `document.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button#connect").click()` or
- `document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()`

were throwing errors.

I had to adapt them to the following:

**Version 1:**

```
function ClickConnect(){
  console.log("Connnect Clicked - Start"); 
  document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
  console.log("Connnect Clicked - End"); 
};
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```

**Version 2:**
If you would like to be able to stop the function, here is the new code:

```js
var startClickConnect = function startClickConnect(){
    var clickConnect = function clickConnect(){
        console.log("Connnect Clicked - Start");
        document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
        console.log("Connnect Clicked - End"); 
    };

    var intervalId = setInterval(clickConnect, 60000);

    var stopClickConnectHandler = function stopClickConnect() {
        console.log("Connnect Clicked Stopped - Start");
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        console.log("Connnect Clicked Stopped - End");
    };

    return stopClickConnectHandler;
};

var stopClickConnect = startClickConnect();
```

In order to stop, call:

```
stopClickConnect();
```

Comment: I have tried the above methods, and a few other blogs. By far, and relevant to the present day, both of your codes work error free. Thank you :)

Comment: "[...by March 2021 none of these methods work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-can-i-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting?page=2&tab=createdasc#comment118402191_57113226)"

Comment: 2023: this code works

Answer (score 29):

Well, this is working for me:

Run the following code in the console and it will prevent you from disconnecting.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to open the inspector view. Then go to the console.

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Working");
    document.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button#connect").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

[How to prevent Colaboratory from disconnecting](https://medium.com/@shivamrawat_756/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting-717b88a128c0)

Comment: Thanks this works well for me too.  (I left the same comment here last week but it disappeared. It's important to not lose work, so this answer deserves positive feedback.)

Comment: Not working, still gets disconnected. (Using Firefox Browser 74.0 (64-bit)).

Comment: Does this also work even if you leave the browser window minimized and work with other applications?

Comment: "[...by March 2021 none of these methods work anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-can-i-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting?page=2&tab=createdasc#comment118402191_57113226)"

Answer (score 29):

Create Python code on your PC with *pynput*:

```
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
import time

mouse = Controller()

while True:
    mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
    time.sleep(30)
```

Run this code on your desktop. Then point the mouse arrow over (Colaboratory's left panel - file section) directory structure on any directory.

This code will keep clicking on the directory every 30 seconds, so it will expand and shrink every 30 seconds. So your session will not get expired.

Important - you have to run this code on your PC.

Comment: I tried this and got a DisplayNameError when I import pynput. It is perhaps because we can only access colab through a browser (in a hosted runtime session) and not keyboard/mouse etc.

Comment: this solution works for me, just one modification rather than clicking on the file directory  I click on the comment icon on the colab page, which just opens the comment box and then closes after each 30 sec.

Comment: In the same vein, I've used SikuliX (a Jython wrapper with preset user-input automation tools) to automate mouse movements, and that was enough for 3 hours. It didn't ask me to fill out a captcha. Just put this in a loop: `sleep(random.randint(50, 70)); mouseMove(randint(-20, 20), randint(-20, 20))`

Answer (score 24):

Instead of clicking the <kbd>Connect</kbd> button, I just clicking on the <kbd>Comment</kbd> button to keep my session alive (August 2020):

```
function ClickConnect(){

    console.log("Working");
    document.querySelector("#comments > span").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,5000)
```

Answer (score 12):

I use a [Macro Program](https://www.macrorecorder.com/) to periodically click on the RAM/Disk button to train the model all night. The trick is to configure a macro program to click on the Ram/Disk Colab Toolbar Button twice with a short interval between the two clicks so that even if the Runtime gets disconnected it will reconnect back. (the first click used to close the dialog box and the second click used to RECONNECT).
However, you still have to leave your laptop open all night and maybe pin the Colab tab.

Answer (score 11):

The previous answers with the help of some scripts maybe work well.

I have a solution (or a kind of trick) for that annoying disconnection without scripts, especially when your program must read data from your google drive, like training a [deep learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_learning) network model, where using scripts to do the `reconnect` operation is of no use, because once you disconnect with your Colaboratory, the program is just dead. You should manually connect to your Google Drive again to make your model able to read dataset again, but the scripts will not do that thing.

I've already tested it many times and it worked well.

When you run a program on the Colaboratory page with a browser (I use Chrome), just remember that don't do any operation to your browser once your program starts running, like: switch to other webpages, open or close another webpage, and so on. Just just leave it alone there and waiting for your program finish running. You can switch to another software, like [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JetBrains#IDEs) to keep writing your code, but not switch to another webpage.

I don't know why open or closing or switching to other pages will cause the connection problem of the Colaboratory page, but each time I try to bothered my browser, like do some search job, my connection to Colaboratory will soon break down.

Comment: I will add to your answer that Firefox is working fine with this trick. But for me I turned off sleep mode on my mac and put the browser window in front of all other windows as if i actively working on it. I kept it all night and it works. None of the javascript tricks has worked. One note is I am using Google Colab Pro: so I'm not sure if this will work with free colab.

Comment: @Yasser Sinjab Thanks for your addings, I uses the free version and it works well.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps many of the previous solutions are no longer working. For example, this bellow code continues to create new code cells in Colab, working though. Undoubtedly, creating a bunch of code cells is an inconvenience. If too many code cells are created in some hours of running and there is no enough RAM, the browser may freeze.

<sub>This repetedly creates code cells—</sub>

```js
function ClickConnect(){
console.log("Working"); 
document.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button").click() 
}setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

But I found the code below is working, it doesn't cause any problems. In the Colab notebook tab, click on the `Ctrl + Shift + i` key simultaneously and paste the below code in the console. 120000 intervals are enough.

```js
function ClickConnect(){
console.log("Working"); 
document.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button#connect").click() 
}setInterval(ClickConnect,120000)
```

I have tested this code in firefox, in November 2020. It will work on chrome too.

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```js
function ClickConnect(){
  console.log("Working"); 
  document
    .querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button")
    .shadowRoot
    .querySelector("#connect")
    .click()
}

setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Updating (July 2021).

```
function ConnectButton(){ 
    console.log("Working"); 
    document.querySelector("#connect").click() 
}
setInterval(ConnectButton, 60000);
```

Comment: Updating what? Code in a previous answer? What answer? Something else? What does it refer to?

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe the JavaScript solutions work anymore. I was doing it from within my notebook with:

```
    from IPython.display import display, HTML
    js = ('<script>function ConnectButton(){ '
           'console.log("Connect pushed"); '
           'document.querySelector("#connect").click()} '
           'setInterval(ConnectButton,3000);</script>')
    display(HTML(js))
```

When you first do a Run all (before the JavaScript or Python code has started), the console displays:

```
Connected to
wss://colab.research.google.com/api/kernels/0e1ce105-0127-4758-90e48cf801ce01a3/channels?session_id=5d8...
```

However, ever time the JavaScript runs, you see the console.log portion, but the click portion simply gives:

```
Connect pushed

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
 at ConnectButton (<anonymous>:1:92)
```

Others suggested the button name has changed to #colab-connect-button, but that gives same error.

After the runtime is started, the button is changed to show RAM/DISK, and a drop down is presented. Clicking on the drop down creates a new `<DIV class=goog menu...>` that was not shown in the DOM previously, with 2 options "Connect to hosted runtime" and "Connect to local runtime".  If the console window is open and showing elements, you can see this DIV appear when you click the dropdown element. Simply moving the mouse focus between the two options in the new window that appears adds additional elements to the DOM, as soon as the mouse looses focus, they are removed from the DOM completely, even without clicking.

Answer (score 8):

You can bookmark the notebook to make it stay connected:

```js
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on star button"); 
    document.querySelector("iron-icon#star-icon").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```

Now you can see the blinking of the star every minute.

Comment: document.querySelector("iron-icon#star-icon") is now null. So I just found the jspath for an expand button on one of my colab steps and replaced the star icon element with that expand element. 1. In the elements panel, right-click that expand icon element. 2. copy->copy jspath. For me it was `document.querySelector("#cell-bbKbx185zqlz > div.main-content > div.editor-container.horizontal > div.text-top-div > div > span > h1 > paper-icon-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#icon")`. This works for a certain amount of time, but other comments say that, in time, a captcha will appear.

Answer (score 7):

Using Python with [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29):

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')

notebook_url = ''
driver.get(notebook_url)

# run all cells
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.F9)
time.sleep(5)

# click to stay connected
start_time = time.time()
current_time = time.time()
max_time = 11*59*60 #12hours

while (current_time - start_time) < max_time:
    webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE).perform()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-toolbar"]/colab-connect-button').click()
    time.sleep(30)
    current_time = time.time()
```

Comment: [Likely no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-can-i-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting/58275370#58275370).

Answer (score 7):

The solution in the YouTube video *"[How to prevent Google Colab from disconnecting | A simple solution](https://youtu.be/78rSqtkw3Gk)"* worked for me.

Install the pynput library that allows you to control and monitor input devices.

```
pip install pynput
```

Now execute this code on your local machine and place the mouse cursor in an empty cell in the Colab notebook being run.

```
from pynput.mouse import Controller,Button
import time

mouse = Controller()

while True:
    mouse.click(Button.left,1)
    print('clicked')

    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried the code in previous answers, but they did not work for me. So here is my JavaScript code for reconnecting.

```
let interval = setInterval(function(){
let ok = document.getElementById('ok');
if(ok != null){
   console.log("Connect pushed");
ok.click();
}},60000)
```

You can use it with the same way (run it on the console of your browser) to run it.

If you want to stop the script, you can enter `clearInterval(interval)` and want to run again `setInterval(interval)`.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```js
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Working"); 
    document.querySelector("paper-icon-button").click()
}
Const myjob = setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```

If isn't working, try clear it by running:

```js
clearInterval(myjob)
```

Answer (score 5):

This one worked for me (it seems like they changed the button classname or id):

```js
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Working");
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Answer (score 4):

The JavaScript code below works for me. Credits to [@artur.k.space](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bengaliai-cv19/discussion/133857#763790).

```
function ColabReconnect() {
    var dialog = document.querySelector("colab-dialog.yes-no-dialog");
    var dialogTitle = dialog && dialog.querySelector("div.content-area>h2");
    if (dialogTitle && dialogTitle.innerText == "Runtime disconnected") {
        dialog.querySelector("paper-button#ok").click();
        console.log("Reconnecting...");
    } else {
        console.log("ColabReconnect is in service.");
    }
}
timerId = setInterval(ColabReconnect, 60000);
```

In the Colab notebook, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + the <kbd>I</kbd> key simultaneously. Copy and paste the script into the prompt line. Then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> before closing the editor.

By doing so, the function will check every 60 seconds to see if the onscreen connection dialog is shown, and if it is, the function would then click the <kbd>OK</kbd> button automatically for you.

Answer (score 4):

Just run the code below after the cell you want to run to save from data loss.

```
!python
```

Also to exit from this mode, write

```
exit()
```

Comment: Related: *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/)*.

Answer (score 4):

The most voted answer certainly works for me but it makes the Manage session window popping up again and again.
I've solved that by auto clicking the refresh button using browser console like below

```
function ClickRefresh(){
    console.log("Clicked on refresh button"); 
    document.querySelector("paper-icon-button").click()
}
setInterval(ClickRefresh, 60000)
```

Feel free to contribute more snippets for this at this gist https://gist.github.com/Subangkar/fd1ef276fd40dc374a7c80acc247613e

Answer (score 4):

This code keep clicking "Refresh folder" in the file explorer pane.

```js
function ClickRefresh(){
  console.log("Working"); 
  document.querySelector("[icon='colab:folder-refresh']").click()
}
const myjob = setInterval(ClickRefresh, 60000)
```

Comment: Note that the file explorer/folder pane must be expanded for this one to work.

Answer (score 4):

[GNU Colab](https://github.com/tallero/gnucolab) lets you run a standard persistent desktop environment on top of a Colaboratory instance.

Indeed it contains a mechanism to not let machines die of idling.

Here's a [video demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1X2Cfg-330).

Answer (score 4):

Okay I've found a nifty solution that will get rid of the

> Active session

pop up automatically. We'll need 2 function for that,

same procedure as earlier. Inspect> console > paste function one by one

> 1

```
function clickConnect() {
    try {
         document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
        // this also works, if above one doesn't work, comment it and uncomment below one
        //document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.getElementById('connect').click();
        setTimeout(clickDismiss, 500);
        console.log("Keeping Colab Alive!");    
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

> 2

```
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

> 3

```
async function clickDismiss() {
    
    try {   
        
        // click manage session button
        document.querySelector("colab-usage-display").shadowRoot.querySelector("paper-button").click();
    
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
        try {
            // leave from manage session window
            await sleep(1000);
            document.querySelector('colab-sessions-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('.dismiss').click();
                } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
        try {   
            // click close button
            await sleep(1000);
            document.querySelector("paper-tab").querySelector("paper-icon-button").shadowRoot.getElementById('icon').click();
                } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    
}
```

> 4

```
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000);
```

EDIT:

So if you don't like doing all this stuff manually there is a way to automate all this!

Way_1. Use this [Chrome Extension](https://github.com/sobuj53/colabAlive/blob/master/colabAlivev1.2.zip) and done

or

Way_2.

1. Use [Page-Manipulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-manipulator/mdhellggnoabbnnchkeniomkpghbekko) extension
2. Click on it then click add Java Script button > + New + > filename
3. Say file name is ColabAlive > Make
4. Active Website = `colab.research.google.com`
5. Matching pages = **Recursive**
6. Then use below code,

```js
// 1
function clickConnect() {
    try {
        document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
        // this also works, if above one doesn't work, comment it and uncomment below one
        //document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.getElementById('connect').click();
        setTimeout(clickDismiss, 500);
        console.log("Keeping Colab Alive!");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

//2
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

//3
async function clickDismiss() {

    try {

        // click manage session button
        document.querySelector("colab-usage-display").shadowRoot.querySelector("paper-button").click();

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    try {
        // leave from manage session window
        await sleep(1000);
        document.querySelector('colab-sessions-dialog').shadowRoot.querySelector('.dismiss').click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    try {
        // click close button
        await sleep(1000);
        document.querySelector("paper-tab").querySelector("paper-icon-button").shadowRoot.getElementById('icon').click();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
//4 
setInterval(clickConnect, 60000);
```

7. Click Active and then reload > done

[Credit goes to Oshayr, Albert Einstein](https://github.com/Oshayr/colabAlive/blob/master/src/inject/inject.js) and everyone who posted their solution here.

Answer (score 4):

As of `June 2023`, here's the working javascript code for preventing Google colab from disconnecting due to inactivity.

```js
 function keepAliveProgrammatically() {
  document.querySelector('colab-connect-button').shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
}
```

The function above is responsible for clicking the `compute resources` button It is clicked after every 6 seconds.
The code snippet below is responsible for running the function.

```js
const keepAliveProgrammaticallyInterval = setInterval(() => {
    keepAliveProgrammatically();
}, 6000);
```

To stop the code, use the code snippet below.

```js
clearInterval(keepAliveProgrammaticallyInterval);
```

Comment: this is working in March 2024

Answer (score 4):

Version July 2023:

```
function ConnectButton() {
    console.log("trying to click connect button");

    let colabConnectButton = document.querySelector("colab-connect-button");
    if (colabConnectButton && colabConnectButton.shadowRoot) {
        let actualButton = colabConnectButton.shadowRoot.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button#connect");
        if (actualButton) {
            actualButton.click();
            console.log("connect button clicked");
        } else {
            console.log("button not found");
        }
    } else {
        console.log("button not found");
    }
}
setInterval(ConnectButton, 60000);
```

Comment: Add an explanation, please.

Comment: Can't say conclusively, but this seems to work. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using jQuery (it seems that Colaboratory includes jQuery by default).

```
function ClickConnect(){
  console.log("Working");
  $("colab-toolbar-button").click();
}
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000);
```

Comment: This one does not work: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at ClickConnect (<anonymous>:3:3)`

Answer (score 3):

I have a problem with these JavaScript functions:

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```

They print the "Clicked on connect button" on the console before the button is actually clicked.

As you can see from different answers to this question, the id of the connect button has changed a couple of times since Google Colab was launched. And it could be changed in the future as well.

So if you're going to copy an old answer to this question, it may say "Clicked on connect button", but it may actually not do that. Of course, if the clicking won't work, it will print an error on the console, but what if you may not accidentally see it?

So you better do this:

```
function ClickConnect(){
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

And you'll definitely see if it truly works or not.

Answer (score 3):

The following *latest* solution works for me:

```
function ClickConnect(){
  colab.config
  console.log("Connnect Clicked - Start"); 
  document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
  console.log("Connnect Clicked - End");
};
setInterval(ClickConnect, 60000)
```

Comment: Consider including an explanation for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am not a Python guy nor I do know what the actual use of this 'Colab' is. I use it as a build system, lol. And I used to setup ssh forwarding in it and then put this code and just leave it running and yeah it works.

```
import getpass
authtoken = getpass.getpass()
```

Comment: How does it work? While I execute a cell that take a long time it is impossible to run another cell with e.g. getting a password.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to avoid all the annoying dialog boxes appearing while you work when trying to simulate the click on the toolbar connect button every minute. you can just copy paste this to your console, call the method and you can work on your notebook.

```
function connectRefresher() {
       window.ConnectButtonIntervalId = setInterval(function ConnectButton(){
                console.log("connected"); 
                document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect").click();
                document.querySelector("colab-sessions-dialog").shadowRoot.querySelector("#footer > div > paper-button").click();
                console.log("closed the dialog!!"); 
            },60000);
    }
    
function clearRefresher() { 
           console.log("clear Interval called !!");
           clearInterval(window.ConnectButtonIntervalId);
    }

 connectRefresher(); //to connect the refresher
 clearRefresher(); //to disconnect the refresher
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Python to press the arrow keys. I added a little bit of randomness in the following code as well.

```
from pyautogui import press, typewrite, hotkey
import time
from random import shuffle

array = ["left", "right", "up", "down"]

while True:
    shuffle(array)
    time.sleep(10)
    press(array[0])
    press(array[1])
    press(array[2])
    press(array[3])
```

Comment: by the way you probably want to access the contents of `array`, this code appears to be wholly determined to press L, R, U, D each time

Comment: Why not `for key in array: press(key)`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution until I found a Python 3 script that randomly moved the mouse back and forth and clicked, always on the same place. But that's enough to fool Colaboratory into thinking I'm active on the notebook, and it will not disconnect.

```
import numpy as np
import time
import mouse
import threading

def move_mouse():
    while True:
        random_row = np.random.random_sample()*100
        random_col = np.random.random_sample()*10
        random_time = np.random.random_sample()*np.random.random_sample() * 100
        mouse.wheel(1000)
        mouse.wheel(-1000)
        mouse.move(random_row, random_col, absolute=False, duration=0.2)
        mouse.move(-random_row, -random_col, absolute=False, duration = 0.2)
        mouse.LEFT
        time.sleep(random_time)


x = threading.Thread(target=move_mouse)
x.start()
```

You need to install the needed packages: `sudo -H pip3 install <package_name>`

You just need to run it (in your local machine) with `sudo` (as it takes control of the mouse) and it should work, allowing you to take full advantage of Colaboratory's 12h sessions.

**Credits:**  [For those using Colab (Pro): Preventing Session from disconnecting due to inactivity](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bengaliai-cv19/discussion/133857)

Comment: I suspect you would want to put it in a separate thread as well :D

Comment: @FalconUA, Last night I left Colab running on my PC and when I woke up in the morning, I found it still running. I guess the script works well, but I got some warnings about thread, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

```
function ClickConnect()
{
    console.log("Working...."); 
    document.querySelector("paper-button#comments").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect, 600)
```

This worked for me, but use it wisely.

Answer (score 2):

```
var startColabHandler = function startColabHandler(interval = 60000, enableConnectButton = false) {
    console.log("colabHandler - configure - start: " + new Date());
    
    var colabClick = function colabClick() {
        console.log("colabHandler - click - start: " + new Date());
        
        if (enableConnectButton === true) {
            var button1 = document.querySelector("#top-toolbar > colab-connect-button").shadowRoot.querySelector("#connect");
            
            if (button1) {
                button1.click()
            }
        }
        
        button2 = document.querySelector("html body colab-dialog.yes-no-dialog paper-dialog div.buttons paper-button#ok");
        
        if (button2) {
            button2.click()
        }
        
        console.log("colabHandler - click - end: " + new Date());
    };

    var intervalId = setInterval(colabClick, interval);

    window.stopColabHandler = function stopColabHandler() {
        console.log("colabHandler - stop - start: " + new Date());
        
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        
        console.log("colabHandler - stop - start: " + new Date());
    };

    console.log("colabHandler - configure - end: " + new Date());
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("connect").click() // Change id here
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Try the above code. It worked for me:)

Answer (score 0):

This snippet when run in **colab** or **kaggle** seems to work:

```
from IPython.display import Audio
import numpy as np

Audio(np.array([0] * 2 * 3600 * 3000, dtype=np.int8), normalize=False, rate=3000, autoplay=True)

# Audio([None] * 2 * 3600 * 3000, normalize=False, rate=3000, autoplay=True)
```

Explanation: the basic idea is to generate a large engouh numpy array and play it as an audioclip with a counter running.

- [None] * 2 * 3600 * 3000: enough values to play for 2 hours to keep the session alive
- `dtype=np.int8`: allocate a single byte, it's all zero anyway.
- `2 * 3600`: 2 hours, `3000` is the smallest sample rate (see below) to enable a running counter.
- `rate`: sample rate
- `normalize=False`: since it's all zero, the default normalize=True will result in a `divide by zerro` warning
- `autoplay=True`: no need to click to play the clip.

It takes a few seconds for the widget to appear and another few seconds for the clip to start autoplaying.
[image]

Data for one hour (`np.array([0] * 2 * 3600 * 3000, dtype=np.int8)`) appears to require 100M RAM.

The alternative (`Audio([None] * 2 * 3600 * 3000, normalize=False, rate=3000, autoplay=True)`) wont need the `numpy` lib but will require more RAM.

`Audio` can also play a local audiofile (in colab or kaggle)  or something from a url. Check Audio's doc for more details.

Answer (score -1):

This is just for people who work with the Ipywidget library. If you don't, it may not be useful for you.

Prevent using Ipywidgets.

Ipywidgets and similar packages that they prepare buttons, text fields, etc., complete a cell after a run in Jupiter or Colab.

Colab saves the last time you ran a cell and if you train your model with these packages then it thinks that you are idle, so after 30 minutes it will make you disconnect.

[image: Like this]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the answer is ambiguous

Comment: The two sentences with *"Prevent using"* and *"they prepare buttons"* are *incomprehensible* (words left out?). Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70672769/edit) it?

Answer (score -1):

When all else fails, you can get background execution by subscribing to [Google Colab Pro+](https://colab.research.google.com/signup)