# Prevent a Google Colab Process from being disconnected

Tags: google-colaboratory

Suppose I have to move out 3 hours away from my girlfriend's apartment, and I am running a Colab Environment. I can't stop the process and I need to bring my computer with me. How can I prevent the running process from being disconnected?

I have tried that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting?rq=1), but I think the Google Colab Interface has changed a bit, so the answers are no longer up-to-date.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many answers there. Currently for me works perfectly to go to the console and type

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("colab-connect-button").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Take note that this should prevent disconnecting after each 1.5 hours of inactivity, but each runtime, if you don't have Colab Pro, will be terminated after 12 hours.

Edit:

I have tested my self and come up that this **works**:

```
function ClickConnect(){
    console.log("Clicked on connect button"); 
    document.querySelector("#ok").click()
}
setInterval(ClickConnect,60000)
```

Note that it will throw an error, its ok, it means that the Disconnection notification is not shown. Once it appear it will be clicked to reconnect.

Comment: I think it is 12 hours with standard colab and 24 hours with colab pro

Answer (score 2):

There is this article from towards science that might help you [prevent colab from disconecting](https://medium.com/@shivamrawat_756/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting-717b88a128c0)

As a second thought, I think that as long as your laptop stays connected and active to a network it will keep running, so, an alternative is to use your phone as a hotspot to connect; use ethernet && wifi all together in order when you remove the cable you'll still be connected. But you have to keep your laptop open so you need battery fully charged; otherwise use a different device to start colab from like phone or tablet.