# How to prevent google colab from disconnecting when accessing through ssh?

Tags: python, linux, ssh, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Q: Is there any way to prevent Google Colab from disconnecting on a timeout if accessing via ssh ?

If we are using google colab through browser , its pretty easy to keep it running which is explained well in this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting) .One just need to use a javascript code which automatically taps on the connect button every minute

I am currently using colab through my android device . I set it up to access via ssh in google colab website and use a ssh client to connect

I wanted to know if there is something which can be done to prevent these frequent disconnections if using google colab through ssh ?
My google colab keeps disconnecting every 5,10 mins after i close the browser while accessing it via ssh . i think this happens because even though i am using colab in ssh , google thinks its idle because nothing is being done thorugh the browser ( just my guess )

On another note -
I should point out here that such behavior does not violate Google Colab's Terms of Use, although it is not encouraged according to their FAQ (in short: morally it is not okay to use up all of the GPUs if you don't really need it.
i just want my ssh colab instance to remain active as long as i don't manually stop runtime through colab website

Comment: Does it also disconnect if you leave a job running through tmux?