# How to enable GPU and stop kicking off from colab when using SSH from VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-colaboratory

I have been following this thread to remote in through VSCode using SSH and ngrok [Configuring Google Colab Like A Pro](https://medium.com/@robertbracco1/configuring-google-colab-like-a-pro-d61c253f7573). It works pretty good. But I have encountered two problems:

Q1. How to setup GPU from VSCode? In the Colab there is a dropdown menu, where you could select GPU to accelerate the training process. But how do we do it in VScode through SSH?

Q2. How to prevent kicking off from Colab? I have read a trick in this [Configuring Google Colab Like a Pro](http://%20https://medium.com/@robertbracco1/configuring-google-colab-like-a-pro-d61c253f7573) and [How to prevent Google Colab from disconnecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting). But they are not intended to be used in the VScode environment through SSH. Basically it has to be run in the Colab cell.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a hack to solve the problems you're facing [I was having the same issue too :) ]

**Steps:**

1. Go to Google Colab, create a new notebook
2. Run this command `!export -p` in a cell; you should see the list of environment variables available to the Colab environment.
3. Find this line in the output `declare -x COLAB_GPU="0"`.
4. In another cell, run the following code:

```
    import os
    os.environ['COLAB_GPU'] = "1"
```

5. Run `!export -p` again, now you should see `declare -x COLAB_GPU="1"`.
6. Now run `!pip install colab_ssh --upgrade`
7. After installing `colab_ssh`, set a *secret_password* and run the following code:

```
    from colab_ssh import launch_ssh_cloudflared
    launch_ssh_cloudflared(secret_password)
```

8. Follow the Client-machine configuration as shown in the output cell.

Assuming you've successfully connected your local VSCode IDE to Colab Kernel over ssh-tunnel, you should now be able to open a notebook from your GDrive and run codes that require GPU access/High-RAM.