# Is there a way to keep my Google Colab running forever even when I'm not on the TAB?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab to run a server with ngrok and it's amazing, but every time I leave it disconnects and my server stops forever. It makes sense for that to happen but is there a way or a loophole? Is there a device I can keep this running on? I've used the `while True:pass` method and it works but requires me too keep the tab open, and I leave my computer closed a lot. Is there a web hosting service that can keep a webpage running on a server forever?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting).

Also notice that with the free version of Colab, your maximum connection time is 12 hours, no matter what. If you pass to the PRO version, that should be extended to a maximum of 24 hours. Look [here](https://colab.research.google.com/signup) for more details