# How to prevent Disconnecting from a runtime (Google Colab)

Tags: google-colaboratory

Im using Colab Free for a long time. My runtime gets disconnected every few minutes so I decided to make a research on Stackoverflow. I find some Chrome DevConsole ([How to prevent Google Colab from disconnecting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-to-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting)) Codes and they were working until this day. Today It started to get disconnected again.

**[Q] How can I keep my runtime alive?**

Comment: i would like to achieve the same.  i note that there were javascript solutions. Is there a Python solution ?

Answer (score -1):

You should move to an ec2 in amazon.

Comment: He wants an answer, not a suggestion!