# How to prevent disconnected when Vscode connect to Colab?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, google-colaboratory

I have connected vscode and colab via the [ssh method](https://colab.research.google.com/github/JayThibs/jacques-blog/blob/master/_notebooks/2021-09-27-connect-to-colab-from-local-vscode.ipynb) successfully.

Whenever I'm idle for a while (less than 3 minutes), Colab disconnects and I have to reconnect and SSH again. This is causing a lot of inconvenience!

I have tried referencing [past solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57113226/how-can-i-prevent-google-colab-from-disconnecting) from Stack Overflow and added the following code (keep running):

```py
while True: pass
```

But it still doesn't work and the disconnection issue continues to occur frequently.

How can I solve this disconnect problem?